# jQuery multiple loops, same IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony, twig

I have a pretty complex problem, with Symfony, TWIG, and JQuery.

I have a form with 2 fields, that I had to loop, because I wanted 15 lines with identical fields, which leads to this :

```
<form>
{% for i in 0..15 %}
<div class="row">
   <section class="col col-3">
    <label class="input"> 
       <input type="text" name="ajax1" id="_ajax1[]" class="ajax1">
    </label>
</section>  

       <section class="col col-1.5">
    <label class="input">
         <input type="text" name="ajax2" id="_ajax2[]" class="ajax2">
    </label>
</section>  
   {% endfor %} 
</form>
```

Then, I use Ajax to autocomplete the 'ajax1' field. I had to loop the autocomplete so I can access to each field, like this :

```
$(".ajax1").each(function(index, elem){
            $(this).autocomplete({
            source : function(requete, reponse){
            var motcle = $(elem).val();
            var DATA = 'motcle=' + motcle;
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url : "{{ path('produit_ajax') }}",
                dataType : 'json',
                data : DATA,

                success : function(donnee){
                    reponse($.map(donnee, function(objet){
                        return objet.nom;
                    }));
                }
            });
            }
        });
        });
```

Everything works pretty well. Now, with the value inside ajax1, I want to populate ajax2. I want to take the ajax1 value, use it in a MySQL request, then populate the ajax2 value with the result of the request. The idea is to keep the loop like the 1st jQuery call..

Pretty tough one for me, I'm sure there is people out there who will find this super easy !

Thanks a lot for your help.

Edit : I really don't know how to do this for ajax2, that's why I'm asking this. If I share a common class for the 2 values, then my autocomplete/my change will apply for both..

Markz

Comment: use a common class, not unique classes

Comment: How do you do that for *ajax2*? I mean what jQuery code have you done yet and what error comes up?